# Export Javascript Web Scrape to Excel

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, export-to-csv, export-to-excel

I have a script that I'm trying to use for university where I access information about an organistaion. The code runs and I get the output of the company description, but I can't figure out how to export it to Excel. Does anyone have any ideas?

Code extract below:

```
async function scrapeProduct(url) {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);

    const [el] = await page.$x('//*[@id="hits"]/div[1]');
    const txt = await el.getProperty('textContent');
    const rawTxt = await txt.jsonValue();

    console.log({rawTxt});

}

scrapeProduct('https://www.ibisworld.com/search/default.aspx?st=International%Game%Technology%Plc')
```

Edit:

I've updated the code to the below:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs');
const stringify = require('csv-stringify');

async function scrapeProduct(url) {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);

    const [el] = await page.$x('//*[@id="hits"]/div[1]');
    const txt = await el.getProperty('textContent');
    const rawTxt = await txt.jsonValue();

    stringify(rawTxt, function(err, output){
        fs.writeFile("output.csv", output);
      });

    console.log({rawTxt});

}

scrapeProduct('https://www.ibisworld.com/search/default.aspx?st=International%Game%Technology%Plc')
```

But now receive the following error message:

```
C:\Users\User\scrape>node scrapers.js
(node:32096) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Invalid argument: got "IGT (Australia) Pty Limited IGT (Australia) Pty Limited is a foreign owned private company, deriving revenue from the supply and servicing of gaming machines and related products. The company employs approximately 300 people, operates in Australia and New Zealand, and is administered from its head office in Macquarie Park, New South Wales. IGT is a wholly owned subsidiary of the UK-based gaming company, International Game Technologies PLC.Subsidiaries: IGT (Australia) Pty Limited, International Game Technology (NZ) LtdKey personnel: Andrew Neagle, Isaac Ai, Claudio Demolli, Phil Osborne, John van Waard, Nigel Turner" at index 0
    at stringify (C:\Users\User\scrape\node_modules\csv-stringify\lib\index.js:480:13)
    at scrapeProduct (C:\Users\User\scrape\scrapers.js:15:5)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:32096) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:32096) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you use a module like `csv-stringify` to convert the JSON output to a CSV, then use `fs` to save that to a file. It also would be feasible to convert the JSON to CSV manually, if you want to avoid a `require`.

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const stringify = require('csv-stringify');

...

stringify(rawTxt, function(err, output){
  fs.writeFile("output.csv", output);
});
```

**Edit:**
To address you're previous edit, I want to add that the data you give to `csv-stringify` must be a 2 dimensional array, or a list of lists. This is you have a grid, like an Excel spreadsheet, which has rows and columns. E.g:

The 2D array input: `[ [a,b,c], [d,e,f], [g,h,i] ]`
Would be converted by `csv-stringify` to: `a,b,c\n,d,e,f\n,g,h,i`\

Which, when opened in a CSV viewer like Excel, would look like:

```
|a|b|c|
-------
|d|e|f|
-------
|g|h|i|
```

when layed out in CSV form in a spreaspeed

Comment: Thank you for your response, I've added an edit to the original question based upon your suggestion. I have installed 'fs' and 'csv-stringify' using npm installer to ensure I've got the required modules.

Comment: From you're edit, it looks like the data you get back is not valid JSON that can be correctly converted to a csv. Take a look at this example, you need to ensure the data you get is a list of lists. This is so, much like an excel spreadsheet, you have cells with X and Y coordinates: https://csv.js.org/stringify/api/#callback-api